# I have permit to stay in Italy as a student, can I go to London to work for 20 hours per week as a part-timer?

Tags: schengen, study, working-visas

I have permit to stay in Italy as a student.

Can I go to London to work for 20 hours per week as a part-timer?

Comment: Great Britain is not in Schengen area.

Comment: @Neusser, even if it was, he couldn't work elsewhere in Schengen with a D visa.